# Html ColSpan/RowSpan not working as expected

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, html-table

I am facing a strange bug that is happening on both IE and Chrome. I have and application that loads a matrix of info but for some reason in a specific case things dont show correctly. By configuration i am able to change the way the info is being displayed and for that i use the rowspan and colspan. 
I am not using any Javascript, just html. This image show what is happening:

Sorry still cant post image but here is the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/gondias/22o07mbt/

```
<table cellspacing="6" cellpadding="0" style="width:558px; background-color:red">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">
            <div class="tile_3x2"></div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2">
            <div class="tile_1x2"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <div class="tile_2x2"></div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <div class="tile_2x2"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" rowspan="1">
            <div class="tile_4x1"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" rowspan="1">
            <div class="tile_4x1"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For some reason the 1st cell in the second row gets extended pushing the following one.
Let me know of any questions you may have.

I think the usage of the rowspan/colspan is correct. Does anyone know what is happening here.
Thanks for the help, i'm really struggling here.

Comment: Why do you have rowspans and empty lines?

Comment: I will always have a matrix of 4colx6rows. Need the rowspan with empty lines because i want those tiles to take the height of two rows. In the same row i may have a tile that takes height of 1 row and that takes the height of 2 rows. In the current example both have the height of 2 rows.

Comment: Translation: I want to span the cell in 2 rows. You can see it in the fiddle. Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you really need to use tables here? Is it used for an email newsletter? You can use only divs with `display: inline-block;` to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to use tables here? Is it used for an email newsletter?
You can use divs with `display: inline-block;` to get the desired result without a table.

If you really need to take this way (not recommended), this is your solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/rcdmk/22o07mbt/1/

```
td {
    width: 132px;
}
```

If you place a border on the `TD` tags you will see what's happening there. The cells (columns) doesn't have specific widths so the browser have to guess based on the content and this is not a consistent behavior between browsers. You will have to just give a width to the cells.

Comment: Hi, that looks like its working good. Thanks for the help. We decided to use tables to be sure where each tile woulb be presented, maybe your sugestion could also work, will give it a try in the future. Thanks for the help