# rowspan not working in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, html-table

I need a specific table construction with borders. I have problem with table in IE. Rowspan not work. Table schedule from 6 cols.
I need use table, because requires marketing platform

I need this view. It's working in Chrome and Firefox:

[image: Imgur]

This is the view in IE:

[image: Imgur]

Code:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td width="600px" style="text-align:center;">
            <table width="600px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="600px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4" width="364px" height="15px"></td>
                                <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" width="236px" height="60px"><a href=""><img src="logo.jpg" alt=" Logo" border="0" /></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4" rowspan="2" width="364px" height="225px" style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000;"><img src="header.jpg" alt=" Header" border="0" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" width="236px" height="180px" style="border-right: 1px solid #000000;"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="6" style="border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000;">
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <td width="175px"></td>
                                <td valign="top" align="right">
                                <p style="padding: 0; margin: 0; font-family: 'Tahoma', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; line-height: 22px;">Loren</p>
                                </td>
                                <td width="80px"></td>
                                </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="6" width="600px" height="30px" style="border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000;"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="29px" height="126px"><img src="icons.jpg" alt=" Icons" border="0" /></td>
                                <td width="146px" height="126px"  style="border-bottom:1px solid #000000;"></td>
                                <td colspan="3" height="126px" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000000;" valign="top" align="right"></td>
                                <td width="80px" height="126px" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000;"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5" width="520px" height="30px" valign="top" align="left"><p  style="padding: 0; margin: 0; font-family: 'Tahoma', sans-serif; font-size: 8px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000;">123</p> </td>
                                <td colspan="1" width="80px" height="30px" valign="top" align="right"><p  style="padding: 0; margin: 0; font-family: 'Tahoma', sans-serif; font-size: 8px; font-weight: bold; color: #000000;">123</p></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html ColSpan/RowSpan not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943450/html-colspan-rowspan-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: i must use only table. That code needed marketing platform.

Comment: What do you mean by "marketing platform"?

Comment: automation system dedicated to marketing activities

Comment: From what I see, the answer there used only tables, and I can't seem to find that "automation system" in the thread

Comment: I do not understand. You know, why not work rowspan in browse Internet Explorer ?

Comment: Although I don't know the real reason, but maybe it is because of something like compatibility-sort of things

Comment: Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304336/rowspan-and-colspan-problems-in-ie), this might help you